# Метод reverse() не выводит перевернутый список

Tags: python-3.x

```
languages = ['Chinese', 'Spanish', 'English', 'Hindi', 'Arabic', 'Bengali', 'Portuguese', 'Russian', 'Japanese', 'Lahnda']

print((languages.reverse()))
```

Выдает следующее:

> None

Comment: Потому что метод reverse никогда ничего не возвращает

Comment: В одну строку вместо `reverse()` используйте `print(languages[::-1])`

Answer (score 0):

```
languages = ['Chinese', 'Spanish', 'English', 'Hindi', 'Arabic', 'Bengali', 'Portuguese', 'Russian', 'Japanese', 'Lahnda']
languages.reverse()
print(languages)
```

Как сказал andreymal, метод reverse ничего не возвращает, поэтому нам сначала нужно перевернуть список, а потом его вывести.

Answer (score 0):

Открываем документацию [Mutable Sequence Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types). В самом низу таблицы:

> ```
> s.reverse()   |  reverses the items of s in place         |  (4)
> ```

Читаем четвёртую ссылку (выделение моё):

> The `reverse()` method modifies the sequence in place for economy of space when reversing a large sequence. To remind users that it operates by side effect, **it does not return the reversed sequence**.

Перевод:

> Метод `reverse()` меняет последовательность на месте чтобы сэкономить место если переворачивается большая последовательность. Чтобы напомнить пользователю про работу через побочный эффект, **метод не возвращает перевернутую последовательность**.

Правильный код

```
languages.reverse()  # перевернули
print(languages)     # напечатали
```